# How to avoid writing a lot of "IF"?

Tags: php

I have a Hearthstone (card game) deckbuilder, which works fine, but I want to add the "subtype" automatically, so users can make their decks even quicker.

Some cards have races or spell types and this can make the subtype.
E.g.: If the deck has more than 5 Demon race typed cards, then it'll be the deck's subtype, but the deck can have more subtypes (after saving the deck, the user can change, if he doesn't like the subtype chosen by the code).

So, if the deck has 10 demons and 10 pirates, then I save the following into the subtype SQL column: "demon,pirate".
It's all good, but the implementation isn't nice.

So let me share some code with you:
I'm looping through all the cards in the deck...

```
if((strpos($card['race'], 'Demon') !== false))
{
   $demon++;
   if($demon >= 6)
   {
      $subtype[0] = 'Demon';
   }
}
if((strpos($card['race'], 'Pirate') !== false))
{
   $pirate++;
   if($pirate >= 6)
   {
      $subtype[1] = 'Pirate';
   }
}
```

Now I think you can see my problem. If we have 10 different races, then it's 10 "IF", if we have 100, then it's 100 "IF".
What should I do?

I was thinking about an array.
To do something like this in the loop:

```
$subtype = array();
if(!empty($card['race']))
{
   array_push($subtype,$card['race']);
}
```

After the loop goes through all the cards, I would do this:

```
sort($subtype); //just to look nice
$count = array_count_values($subtype);
print_r($count);
```

Then my knowledge stops here. How can I work with this?
I get the result like this:

```
Array
(
    [Demon] => 6
    [Murloc] => 4
    [Pirate] => 8
)
```

I want to save to my subtype variable, if it's more than 5. How do I put "Demon" and "Pirate" into a variable?
The end result would be:

```
$subtype = "Demon,Pirate"
```

Comment: [Why storing comma-delimited list in a database is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: You can use `$subtype = explode(',', $card['race'])`

Comment: If you leave all your bits of data crammed into an arbitrary string you're going to be spending the majority of your CPU time running the same `strpos()` calls many thousands of times. Break them out ahead of time and store them in the card metadata. Also, when you find yourself using a bunch of slightly-differently-named variables that all do the exact same thing, it usually means that you should be using an array instead.

Comment: Once you have a 1NF db schema, you'll be able to enjoy techniques like `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT() > 5` and `GROUP_CONCAT_WS()` to eliminate clumsy grouping, counting, filtering, and imploding in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here isn't with the PHP but rather, with the SQL, specifically, with the design of your database. As @Barmar pointed out, the problem here is that you are essentially storing a list (of unspecified length) in a text field in the database. This is poor database design and will require you to write a lot of code to parse the data to do what you want, and you will need to have code both to parse/interpret the data when you retrieve it, and to format it when you save / update it.

A better approach would be to use three tables in your database, one for the card, and one for the type, and then each can have a unique ID. Then create a third table for connecting the two, which contains the ID's of both the cards and types. A card can then have any number of types, including none, and this would correspond to the number of entries in the third table which contained the ID for the card. This is the standard way of denoting a many-to-many relationship. If you want to look up this technique, it is alternatively called a "bridge table", "junction table", or "join table".

In this case, you will have to think a little more when you create a SQL query to pull the data, but this extra work will quickly pay for itself many times over in simplification of your PHP code. For times you don't need the type, you can ignore the tables other than the card. If you want to do something that loops through all types for a particular card, you can then take the card's ID (which presumably you would already have) and then make a SQL query with an inner join of the type table, and the third table, and then loop through all returned rows using a `while ($row->fetch()){}` loop or something similar. This will avoid "if" statements like the ones in your example. It will also make your code more extensible. I.e. if you want to add a new type, you don't need to change your code anywhere, you will just need to add a new entry to the type table.

Another advantage of structuring your database this way is that a lot of things can be done with SQL code now, rather than in PHP. For example, if you want to return the type that has the most representation in your deck, this is easy, you can do it by doing inner joins of all three tables and using `COUNT(card_id)` and `GROUP BY (type_id)`. Now your PHP has been reduced to a single series of statements to pass a query to the database and then retrieve the information, for what previously would have been many complex lines of code.

And this is only one of many advantages of doing it this way. There are nearly endless possibilities of things that are easy to do with this setup, that would be cumbersome under your old setup.

Comment: Instead of answering, shall we close with [Database Design: Is it bad to keep delimited strings in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1690017/2943403) or [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/2943403) or Barmar's link?  (maybe all of them)